# Middleware in Java with usage of RMI, JMS or other tools?

Tags: java, jms, rmi, communication, middleware

I have to deal with a middleware solution for a self adaptive system in java. Basically there should be a communication (sending/receiving of data/instructions) between managed resources (MR) and adaptation logics (AL). In a nutshell, sensors of the AL should be able to send instructions and receive data, while probes of the MR can send data and receive instructions handled by the middleware. Moreover there should be some kind of registration process to find relevant components for a connection (like publish subscribe).

Since this topic is new to me I found Java RMI or Java Messaging Service to be relevant for a possible implementation. But since I dont have deep knowledge, I hope you guys can tell me what tools given by Java is the best for implementing this middleware.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can't use RMI unless the peers are written in Java, and you can't use JMS unless they have access to a message broker. Unclear what you're asking; too broad; and recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: Well my tastk is to create a middleware in Java that stores data in a database and to handle the datastream via publish subscribe between various components. Rmi was nice due to de decoupling between several components, but it does not really support the publish subscripe mechanism that I also need to implement.